# Laravel Create Route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with a simple implementation of laravel. I have a very simple model called **contact** (id, title, mobile etc) which also has a simple Controller which handles functions for returning views etc. For some reason though I am unable to setup a simple route for returning a form to create a new **contact**. For example I would like the following:

```
Route::get('/contacts/create', 'ContactsController@create');
```

and below is the following function in the controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('contacts.create');
}
```

The view is very simple and is just displaying text at this point. However when I navigate to /contacts/create I get the following error:

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFLiZ.png)

I'm not sure why this is happening and get seem to find a solution. I also have the following other routes which work perfectly:

```
Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactsController@index');

Route::get('/contacts/{contact}', 'ContactsController@show');
```

And strangely enough when I create a route such as /contacts/test/other I do not get the error.

I imagine I am doing something stupid here at some point, any help you can give would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me insane!

Thanks.

Comment: where have you used the Contact model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is looking for a contact with the *name* or *id*; **create**. So you should make a route create before your any route.

```
Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactsController@index');
Route::get('/contacts/create', 'ContactsController@create');
Route::get('/contacts/{contact}', 'ContactsController@show');
```